# SQL converting number of days to weeks

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I have a SQL table with a column that says number of days, and contains entries like 23, 26, 45, etc...
I am trying to convert each entry to a "week number". In essence, what I mean is that if my day entry is between 0 and 6, then, this is Week 1, if it is 7 and 13, then this is Week 2, 14 and 20, week 3, etc... Is there an "efficient" way to do this in SQL?

Thanks.
Thomas.

Comment: All the way up to Week 52?

Comment: aren't you just `floor(day/7)+1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need just the standard divide function.  It ignores the remainder:

```
SELECT (Days / 7) + 1
```

Comment: Due to integer math, it ignores the remainder.

Comment: Hi. Why the +1?

Comment: because 6/7 = 0 and you said 0-6 is week 1

Comment: Hi. Okay, that makes perfect sense. Thanks. I upvoted you, but I don't have a "reputation" as yet to make it display publicly!

Comment: in 15-30 minutes you'll be able to "Accept" this as the answer.  This allows others to post and provide alternatives which may suit your needs better.

Comment: SELECT (14/ 7) + 1 will equal to 3. Is that correct? Should it not be 2? 
Week 1: Day 1 through 7
Week 2: Day 8 through 14

Answer (score 1):

You can try this and no need to add +1;

```
SELECT (Days / 7.00)
```

Comment: This returns decimals.

Comment: Yes, this would provide the exact result if the Days is < 7, convert the decimal using ROUND() to get the required output.

Comment: Round = Bad.  6/7 would yield 1 when it's really week 0.

Comment: try this: SELECT CAST(ROUND((6 / 7.0),2) AS NUMERIC(18,2)), will round to two decimals